# java Processbuilder doesn't work properly

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder

I'm attempting to create a program that opens and closes a .exe application. This is part of the code:

```
public class BotHelper {
private static String pathToBot = "C:\\Users\\valdemar\\Downloads\\Release\\application.exe"; //bot path
private static Process p; //bot process
private static int giorni; //days of activity (chosen by user)
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        p = new ProcessBuilder(pathToBot).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
...
```

The issue with this is that the code actually doesn't seem to do anything. 
It doesn't run the application, and swapping the name of the application with the name of a batch file that runs the application gives me a message stating that it can't find the said application.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must run the batch script from `cmd`. What I mean is that you can't directly execute the batch script, but instead have to execute `cmd` and run the script from there. So, the example command would be: `cmd.exe /C C:\path\to\script.bat`. Then the `Process` would be created as so:

```
p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe /C " + pathToScript).start();
```